# Hide all controllers from url

Tags: php, url-rewriting, yii

I've used Yii's urlManager to rewrite my url from mypage.com/controller/view to mypage.com/view. But I have more than one Controller and would like to apply this on all of them. Can this be done?

My current urlManager:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
      'urlFormat'=>'path',
      'showScriptName'=>false,
      'rules'=>array(
      '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
      ),
 ),
```

Comment: You need a rule for each controller I believe.

Comment: I've tried the same rule as I have for SiteController (shown in my urlManager above) for all controllers but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First way:

```
'<action:(login|logout|about)>' => 'site/<action>',
'<action:(view|edit)>' => 'product/<action>',
```

Second way to implement this feature is to use [Using Custom URL Rule Classes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes)